# How to add predefined values in plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, properties-file

I have to create a configuration plist. In that I want to set some predefined values for a field, so that some one else can select value from a drop down in plist. Some thing like this screen, how user can select languages from drop down. [image: this is a plist from XCode]

Is it possible to define a set of preconfigured values in Plist?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should start by reading the Property List Serialization guide. 
Then play with the property list editor built in to xcode. 
Generally you'll have an array of dictionaries in your plist for something like a list of options to choose from. 
Foundation collections like `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` even have convenience class factory methods for basically loading from a `plist`.

These days JSON is also an alternative.

Comment: In Xcode 7.1 `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns` there are `DVTCorePlistStructDefs.dvtplugin` and `DVTiOSPlistStructDefs.dvtplugin` that looks like what you are talking about and I've edited them but it didn't show up in Xcode's property list type. Has anyone able to do this easier? I've also read through Apple's docs about plists but nothing about adding new property list type.